# How to use Spring @Component annotation with AspectJ compiler

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I excluded part of my project for easier reproduce problem: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/krivochenko/test-aspectj).
When I compile it by Javac everything works as expected. I see logging in console when I open URLs `/user/` and `/user/2/`:

`Access: execution(List ru.krivochenko.demo.user.UserController.getAll())
Access: execution(User ru.krivochenko.demo.user.UserController.getOne(Integer))`

But I wanna use AspectJ compiler. When I switch to it, error occurs:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ru.krivochenko.demo.logging.LoggingAspect: method <init>()V not found`

As I understood it happens because there is not no-args constructor in `LoggingAspect`. If I add it, I get another error, because `logger` is not injected:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at ru.krivochenko.demo.logging.LoggingAspect.beforeGettingUsers(LoggingAspect.java:28) ~[classes/:na]`

So, how we can see, AspectJ ignores Autowired constructor with args.

In branch `via-setter` of my repo I implemented another solution. I removed `@Component` annotation of `LoggingAspect` and replaced constructor injection to setter injection. In `DemoApplication.java` I added `@Bean` configuration of `LoggingAspect`. It works fine, but in some situations it requires getting dependencies from application context. What is the best practice to resolve it?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Spring AOP, even though less powerful and with more overhead due to dynamic proxies, is the default AOP solution built into Spring and also knowing about component wiring. AspectJ, however, is completely independent of Spring and knows zero about it. You can use both together, though, the Spring manual describes the load-time weaving (LTW) approach, though. You are going a third way and use compile-time weaving. First I want to understand why, before we talk tech. What is it you want to achieve with your unorthodox way of combining Spring and AspectJ or cannot achieve in another?

Comment: I wanna use compile-time weaving for improve performance of my application. Also, I know that with Spring AOP it is not possible to intercept nested calls of methods: https://coderanch.com/t/624665/frameworks/Unable-invoke-aspects-public-nested. In the same time I wanna use Spring DI features.
Why do you consider with way unorthodox?

Comment: I already explained why I think it is unorthodox: because the Spring manual describes the LTW approach. But anyway, CTW is an option, unless you want to weave your aspects into Spring or other 3rd party code. As long as your aspects only affect your own code, it is fine. With LTW however, you could also intercept Spring and 3rd party classes. How can I know what you want? I am just explaining. Gonna take a look at your repo now.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Aspects and compile time weaving don't automatically integrate. This is primary because aspectj and spring are fairly separate and I suspect Spring's recommended approach is not to use compile time weaving.

So thus by default Aspects are not spring magic and we need to add a little bit of plumbing to ensure they are.

In this regard, it is important to note that Aspects are not spring managed (they are managed by aspectj so we need to add something to ensure they are).

Thus the reason why you need a parameterless constructor on your aspect (so must use field injection).

Traditionally I have had to add the following piece of xml to my xml config files:

```
<bean id="securityAspect" class="com.<skip>.security.AuthorizationAspect"
        factory-method="aspectOf" autowire="byType" />
```

So this works because the AspectJ compiler adds the static method aspectOf to the aspects and this method is available for acquiring the instance of the Aspect that aspectj creates (and uses).

This method is obviously not available in the source so we can't just add to our application class (DemoApplication):

```
@Bean
public LoggingAspect loggingAspect() {
    return LoggingAspect.aspectOf();
}
```

Then what to do? My next option was to write some reflective code to call this method then having looked at this [very helpful example](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-aspectj/tree/master/ctw) that demonstrates exactly what you need - The Aspects class from AspectJ has a utilty method that does this work for us, so adding the following to our DemoApplication we have success:

```
@Bean
public LoggingAspect loggingAspect() {
    return Aspects.aspectOf(LoggingAspect.class);
}
```

Btw, remove the @Component from the LoggingAspect as that will mean both Aspectj and Spring create an instance of the class...

Btw, I'd also suggest you add the following to your test class to demonstrate the problem in a test:

```
@Autowired
private UserController controller;

@Test
public void contextLoads() {
    controller.getAll();
    controller.getOne(1);
}
```

Btw, other suggestions to address this problem used @Configurable. I suspect this might work but you'll need to make sure you include the spring aspects java in your aspectj compile time config and I suspect it may still not work as I'm not sure the Spring context will be ready in time. i.e. if the Aspect is created before the spring context then @Configurable won't work as the beans to be injected will not yet be created.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to configure the aspect via setter injection looks valid to me. For more information about how to use AspectJ in combination with Spring check out the corresponding [chapter in the Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj), specifically the description about how to [configure AspectJ aspects by Spring IoC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-aj-configure). It is mostly explained in the context of LTW, but it should work pretty much the same for CTW.